# GetBValue Error: Expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

Tags: c++, visual-c++, enums, getpixel

I am writing a simple program to read the pixel at a particular location and get its individual R,G and B values for further processing.
I am able to read the R and the G values but I get an error when I read the B value.

Here is my complete code for reference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int d;
    HDC dc = GetDC(NULL);
    
        COLORREF rcolor = GetRValue(dc, 1, 1);
        COLORREF gcolor = GetGValue(dc, 1, 1);
        COLORREF bcolor = GetBValue(dc, 1, 1);

        ReleaseDC(NULL, dc);
        

        cout << rcolor << endl;
        cout << gcolor << endl;


    cin >> d;
}
```

I am getting an error at this line:
`COLORREF bcolor = GetBValue(dc, 1, 1);`

Here goes the error:

> `#define GetBValue(rgb) (LOBYTE((rgb)>>16))`
>
> `Error: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type`

I tried searching for this error in the color context but could not find any suitable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am able to read the R and the G values but I get an error when I read the G value.

I assume the last one was supposed to be the B value. But anyway, you are not reading *any* of the values correctly. The R and G just happen to compile without error, but will return random bits from the HDC handle value.

What you want is probably this.

```
HDC dc = GetDC(NULL);
COLORREF rgb = GetPixel(dc, 1, 1);

BYTE rcolor = GetRValue(rgb);
BYTE gcolor = GetGValue(rgb);
BYTE bcolor = GetBValue(rgb);

ReleaseDC(NULL, dc);
```

P.S. VC++ 2010 (as an example, and I assume other versions as well) gives warning `"C4002: too many actual parameters for macro 'Get?Value'"` for each of the 3 Get?Value lines in the original code, before the fatal compiler error. It's good practice to compile with warnings set high, and watch them for red flags.

Comment: This is why C-style casting is evil, especially when combined with macros. Inline functions would be just as efficient and much more type safe.

Comment: @MarkRansom Right. That said, I just edited the reply and removed the quoted macros to reduce potential confusion. Whoever is curious can still lookup the P.S. in the original revision of this post.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for correcting my mental typo. Worst of all, `COLORREF rgb2 = RGB(rcolor, gcolor, bcolor);` would have compiled without even a warning with the components (wrongly) declared as COLORREF instead of (correctly) as BYTE. The evils of macros *and* typedefs combined, I guess ;-)